# What does the expression "(и вот) в один прекрасный день" intend to convey?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> И вот **в один прекрасный день** ты начинаешь осознавать, что влюблена в него.

I get the feeling that this (fixed) expression is not about the weather being literally "прекрасный / beautiful / nice" when something has happened, but rather perhaps, I wonder if it is used to describe how suddenly and unexpectedly something has happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There's](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%E2+%EE%E4%E8%ED+%EF%F0%E5%EA%F0%E0%F1%ED%FB%E9+%E4%E5%ED%FC) a direct English parallel

> one fine day

Although in Russian the phrase doesn't necessarily mean it to be literally *beautiful* or *charming*, it's still not used to describe adverse events, except ironically. The antonymous expression for negative events would be

> В один злополучный/злосчастный день....

which nevertheless is too literary for daily use

Comment: I would say that in modern Russian, "в один прекрасный день" is always used with some degree of irony, regardless of whether the event is actually good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "в один прекрасный день" может означать нечто совсем иное, чем истинное счастье. Например: И вот, в один прекрасный день меня уволили. Или: И вот, в один прекрасный день Ельцин передал власть Путину.